# Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

Tags: kubernetes

How to set some curl requests in yaml whit using curlimages/curl?
I get the error "Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse"

I tried these variants:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: croncurl
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: croncurl
            image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "curl -v http://{1}"
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "curl -v http://{2}"
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "curl -v http://{3}"
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "curl -v http://{4}"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

```
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "curl -v http://{1}"
            - "curl -v http://{2}"
            - "curl -v http://{3}"
            - "curl -v http://{4}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-:`

```
command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "curl -v http://{1} -: http://{2} -: http://{3}"
```